# Get Stock Overview from Investing.com using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the following information
[image]

from Investing.com.

Code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/nvidia-corp")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

#get the element
soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc',
                       }).text
```

returns 139.37, which is the value of prev.close.

How can I extend the code to get the remaining values?
135.91 -141.71 for Day's Range, 29.74B for Revenue, ..?

Looking at inspect, each of these seem to be under the same span class.
[image]

With a for loop,

```
 for element in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5'}):
        print(soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc'
                           }).text)
```

I get 139.37 for as many as the items there:

```
139.37
139.37
139.37
139.37
139.37
....
139.37
```

Printing the element of the find_all:

```
   for element in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5'}):
        #print(soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc'}).text)
        print('')
        print(element)

results in:
<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Prev. Close</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="prevClose"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>139.37</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Day's Range</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="dailyRange"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>135.91</span><span></span></span><span class="ml-1 mr-1">-</span><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>141.71</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Revenue</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="revenue"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>29.74</span><span>B</span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Open</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="open"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>141</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>52 wk Range</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="weekRange"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>132.76</span><span></span></span><span class="ml-1 mr-1">-</span><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>346.47</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>EPS</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="eps"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>3.09</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Volume</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="volume"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>74,134,559</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Market Cap</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="marketCap"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>339.67</span><span>B</span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Dividend (Yield)</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="dividend"><div class="flex"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>0.16</span><span></span></span><div class="ml-1"><span>(</span><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>0.12</span><span>%</span></span><span>)</span></div></div></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Average Vol. (3m)</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="avgVolume"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>52,794,574</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>P/E Ratio</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="ratio"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>45.51</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Beta</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="beta"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>1.65</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>1-Year Change</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="oneYearReturn"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>-39.07</span><span>%</span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Shares Outstanding</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="sharesOutstanding"><span class="key-info_dd-numeric__2cYjc"><span>2,489,000,000</span><span></span></span></dd></div>

<div class="flex justify-between border-b py-2 desktop:py-0.5"><dt>Next Earnings Date</dt><dd class="font-bold" data-test="nextEarningDate"><a class="inv-link" data-test="link-key-info" href="/equities/nvidia-corp-earnings">Nov 17, 2022</a></dd></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.investing.com/equities/nvidia-corp"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

out = {}
for dt in soup.select("dt"):
    k = dt.get_text(strip=True)
    v = dt.find_next("dd").get_text(strip=True)
    out[k] = v

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Prev. Close": "139.37",
    "Day's Range": "135.91-141.71",
    "Revenue": "29.74B",
    "Open": "141",
    "52 wk Range": "132.76-346.47",
    "EPS": "3.09",
    "Volume": "74,134,559",
    "Market Cap": "339.67B",
    "Dividend (Yield)": "0.16(0.12%)",
    "Average Vol. (3m)": "52,794,574",
    "P/E Ratio": "45.51",
    "Beta": "1.65",
    "1-Year Change": "-39.07%",
    "Shares Outstanding": "2,489,000,000",
    "Next Earnings Date": "Nov 17, 2022",
}
```

Comment: that's amazing. Thanks.
Could you also add some explanations of the logic behind to the code?

Comment: @Luc When you inspect the HTML you will see the labels are inside `<dt>` tag and the value is right next inside `<dd>` tag. So I construct the dictionary where keys are values in `<dt>` and values are next `<dd>`.